# XML SAXParserException in android

Tags: android, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, android-xml

Using the following I code I am trying to get List of nodes in xml, but the application crashes throwing a saxparser exception.

this is the xml I am trying to use

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Root><ResponseCode>1</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Reported Successfully</ResponseMessage><ResultSet><Post><id>1</id><title>Garbage Problem near my home</title><comment>We the citizens have been facing the problems of garbage since 2004 , kindly fix it , authorities are concerned</comment><imagepath></imagepath><cordx>24.818688</cordx><cordy>67.029686</cordy><tag>Garbage</tag><userid>1</userid><departmentid>1</departmentid><response></response><createdOn>2013-03-23 14:44:43</createdOn><status>2</status></Post></ResultSet></Root>
```

and this is the code I am trying to use to get  from the xml

```
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(result));
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();
String code = xPath.evaluate("/Root/ResponseCode/text()", is);
if(code.compareTo("1")==0){
    Log.d("Responce Code", code);
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//Post", is,XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
    Node n=nodeList.item(i);
    Element element = (Element) n;
    Log.d("LIST DATA", element.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-24 12:31:16.357: I/Post service Response(901): <?xml version="1.0"?><Root><ResponseCode>1</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Reported Successfully</ResponseMessage><ResultSet><Post><id>1</id><title>Garbage Problem near my home</title><comment>We the citizens have been facing the problems of garbage since 2004 , kindly fix it , authorities are concerned</comment><imagepath></imagepath><cordx>24.818688</cordx><cordy>67.029686</cordy><tag>Garbage</tag><userid>1</userid><departmentid>1</departmentid><response></response><createdOn>2013-03-23 14:44:43</createdOn><status>2</status></Post></ResultSet></Root>
03-24 12:31:16.498: D/Responce Code(901): 1
03-24 12:31:16.537: W/System.err(901): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
03-24 12:31:16.537: W/System.err(901):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:129)
03-24 12:31:16.537: W/System.err(901):  at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:474)
03-24 12:31:16.548: W/System.err(901):  at com.teamgreen.greenit.HistoryActivity$1.run(HistoryActivity.java:69)
03-24 12:31:16.548: W/System.err(901): --------------- linked to ------------------
03-24 12:31:16.548: W/System.err(901): javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
03-24 12:31:16.577: W/System.err(901):  at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:479)
03-24 12:31:16.577: W/System.err(901):  at com.teamgreen.greenit.HistoryActivity$1.run(HistoryActivity.java:69)
03-24 12:31:16.587: W/System.err(901): Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
03-24 12:31:16.587: W/System.err(901):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:129)
03-24 12:31:16.587: W/System.err(901):  at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:474)
03-24 12:31:16.607: W/System.err(901):  ... 1 more
```

Comment: what is the exception? please upload the logcat

Comment: so i removed asnwer because doesnt work my idea so this is then strange problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, once InputStream is consumed we cannot use it again in this case first it was used to get response code from the xml, the next time it was used to post, and here the exception occurs, because next time we call it, it has nothing to give, so parsing fails. The problem was solved by creating another new object of the InputStream and then using it to get posts from xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SAXXmlParser {
    private static final String ROOT_ELEMENT="Root";

    private String ResponseCode="ResponseCode";
    private String ResponseMessage="ResponseMessage";

    private LinkedHashMap<String,String> resultMap=null;
    private String xml="";

    public SAXXmlParser(String str) {
        this.xml=str;
        resultMap=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    };

    protected InputStream getInputStream() 
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
        return is;
    }

    public LinkedHashMap<String,String> parse()
    {
        RootElement root = new RootElement(ROOT_ELEMENT);
        root.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener()
        {
            public void end()
            {

            }
        });
        root.getChild(ResponseCode).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
        {
            public void end(String body) 
            {
                resultMap.put("ResponseCode",body);
            }
        });
        root.getChild(ResponseMessage).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
        {
            public void end(String body) 
            {
                resultMap.put("ResponseMessage",body);
            }
        });

        try 
        {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

Use this sample class,
And call as,

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> resultMap =new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
SAXXmlParser parser=new parser(xml);
resultMap =parser.parse();
Log.d("ResponseCode",resultMap.get("ResponseCode"));
Log.d("ResponseMessage",resultMap.get("ResponseMessage"));
```